# I am generating a short url by taking an actual url in a node.js project and storing the url in my MongoDB database

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

After the short url is generated, when i am trying to open the url in my browser so that it gets redirected to the original url it displays an error.[This is the error in the browser.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XFCxI.jpg)
I am also attaching my code below :-

```
This is my urlController.js file

// const shortid = require('shortid');
// const crypto = require('crypto');
const validator = require('validator');
const { validationResult } = require('express-validator');
const Url = require('../models/Url');
const { nanoid } = require('nanoid');

const shortenUrl = async (req, res) => {
  const errors = validationResult(req);

  if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
    return res.status(400).json({ errors: errors.array() });
  }

  const { originalUrl } = req.body;

  if (!originalUrl || !validator.isURL(originalUrl)) {
    return res.status(400).json({ msg: 'Invalid original URL' });
  }

  try {
    const shortCode = nanoid(12); // Generate a short, unique identifier
    const shortUrl = `http://localhost:5000/${shortCode}`;

    const url = await Url.create({
      originalUrl,
      shortUrl,
      user: req.user.id,
    });

    res.json({ shortUrl });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error.message);
    res.status(500).send('Server Error');
  }
};

const redirectToOriginalUrl = async (req, res) => {
  const shortUrl = req.params.shortUrl;

  try {
    const url = await Url.findOne({ shortUrl });

    if (!url) {
      console.log('URL not found:', shortUrl);
      return res.status(404).json({ msg: 'URL not found' });
    }

    console.log('Redirecting to:', url.originalUrl);
    res.redirect(url.originalUrl);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error.message);
    res.status(500).send('Server Error');
  }
};

const getUserUrls = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const userUrls = await Url.find({ user: req.user.id });

    res.json(userUrls);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error.message);
    res.status(500).send('Server Error');
  }
};

const updateUrl = async (req, res) => {
  const { id } = req.params;
  const { originalUrl } = req.body;

  try {
    let url = await Url.findById(id);

    if (!url) {
      return res.status(404).json({ msg: 'URL not found' });
    }

    url.originalUrl = originalUrl;

    await url.save();

    res.json(url);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error.message);
    res.status(500).send('Server Error');
  }
};

const deleteUrl = async (req, res) => {
  const { id } = req.params;

  try {
    let url = await Url.findById(id);

    if (!url) {
      return res.status(404).json({ msg: 'URL not found' });
    }

    await url.deleteOne();

    res.json({ msg: 'URL removed' });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error.message);
    res.status(500).send('Server Error');
  }
};

module.exports = {
  shortenUrl,
  redirectToOriginalUrl,
  getUserUrls,
  updateUrl,
  deleteUrl,
};

This code controls all the methods like shortenUrl, redirectToOriginalUrl, etc.
```

```
This is my database schema for Url's to be stored.

const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const urlSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  originalUrl: { type: String, required: true },
  shortUrl: { type: String, required: true, unique: true },
  user: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User',},
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Url', urlSchema);
```

```
This is my urlRoutes.js file

const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const urlController = require('../controllers/urlController');
const authenticate = require('../middleware/authMiddleware');

// @route   POST /api/url/shorten
// @desc    Shorten a URL
// @access  Private
router.post('/shorten', authenticate, urlController.shortenUrl);

// @route   GET /api/url/manage
// @desc    Get user's shortened URLs
// @access  Private
router.get('/manage', authenticate, urlController.getUserUrls);

// @route   PUT /api/url/:id
// @desc    Update a shortened URL
// @access  Private
router.put('/:id', authenticate, urlController.updateUrl);

// @route   DELETE /api/url/:id
// @desc    Delete a shortened URL
// @access  Private
router.delete('/:id', authenticate, urlController.deleteUrl);

// @route   GET /:shortUrl
// @desc    Redirect to the original URL
// @access  Public
router.get('/:shortUrl', urlController.redirectToOriginalUrl);

module.exports = router;
```

```
This is my main index.js file

const express = require('express');
const connectDB = require('./src/config/db');
require('dotenv').config();

const app = express();

// Connect to MongoDB
connectDB();

// Middleware
app.use(express.json({ extended: false }));

// Routes
app.use('/api/auth', require('./src/routes/authRoutes'));
app.use('/api/url', require('./src/routes/urlRoutes'));

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;

app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Server started on port ${PORT}`));
```

What i am doing is that I am shortening the url via a HTTP POST request through Postman and I am getting the shortened url in the form of JSON in  Postman.[This is the image from postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GhfVG.png)
Now after the short url is generated, I am trying to make a GET request so that it displays the original url, but it is throwing error.[This is the error in Postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Evrhz.png)

What I am trying to achieve is that when the short url is generated, the short url works correctly and I can redirect to the original url after opening the short url in the browser and also when I make a GET request in postman via the short url, it redirects me to the original url.

One more thing my url's are stored perfectly in my MongoDB database.

If any more information is needed, i can provide and i am not able to fix this issue at all. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: __All__ your `./src/routes/urlRoutes` routes have the prefix `'/api/url'`, this includes the redirect url.

Comment: For the redirect to original Url, the route is 'http://localhost:5000/<the shortened Url>'. After making a GET request to the above route it should redirect me to the original Url.

Comment: `For the redirect to original url, the route is 'localhost:5000/<the shortened url>'.` No it is not. Try `'localhost:5000/api/url/<the shortened url>'`

Comment: I tried that, but now it is giving me the "if url is not found statement" you can check the code I posted -> redirectToOriginalUrl method in the urlController.js file.  In postman its giving me { "msg" : "URL not found" } as a JSON.

Comment: So what do you think is the error, is my redirect to original url route not configured correctly?

Answer (score 0):

The way you mounted your router means that here:

```js
router.get('/:shortUrl
```

It is implied that the route is actually `/api/url/:shortUrl` because you mounted the router at:

```js
app.use('/api/url', urlController.redirectToOriginalUrl);
```

Change this:

```js
const shortUrl = `http://localhost:5000/${shortCode}`;
```

To this:

```js
const shortUrl = `http://localhost:5000/api/url/${shortCode}`;
```

Then when you look for the `shorturl` you have to do it like:

```js
const url = await Url.findOne({ shortUrl: `http://localhost:5000/api/url/${shortUrl}` });
```

Moving forward you may want to move the route that handles the get requests to `shortUrl` to a different mount point but that is up to you. At the minute the only route you have to handle get requests to the `redirectToOriginalUrl` function is `/api/url/:shortUrl`.